# ¿como hago para mostrar una el resultado de un bucle en una tabla?

Tags: javascript, html, while, html-tabla, bucle-for

Estoy tratando de realizar una pagina que muestre la conversión de 1 hasta 10 dolares, dolar por dolar y que se imprima utilizando un bucle while pero dentro de una tabla, pero hasta ahora no he tenido éxito.
El código que he creado va mas o menos así:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TablaDolar</title>
</head>

<body>

<table width="200" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>Dolares</td>
  <td>Monto</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>

var monto = 0;
var dolar = 17,10;
var a = "";
var vueltas = 0;


while(vueltas < 10){

a = "<table width="200" border="1">"
+ "<tbody>"
+ "<tr>"
+ "<td>" + dolar + "</td>"
+ "<td>" + monto + "</td>"
+ "</tr>"
+ "</tbody>"
+ "</table>";

document.write(a);

vueltas ++;
dolar +;
monto ++;
}
```

Monto indica la cantidad de dolares que se vienen convirtiendo
dolar indica el valor del dolar en pesos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos!!

Tienes varios errores en tu código, para empezar `17,10` debes cambiarlo por `17.10`.

También tienes un typo en `dolar +;`, eso lanza un error.

Si quieres utilizar comillas dobles `"` dentro de un string tienes que escaparlas de esta forma `\"` o bien utilizar comillas simples para encapsularlo hay varias opciones.

Y por último como dijo [Elberth Agreda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/92655/22721) el encabezado de la tabla debe ir fuera del while.

El código me quedo mas o menos así que sería la solución a la pregunta que hiciste:

```js
var monto = 1;
var precioDolar = 17.10;
var pesos = monto * precioDolar;
var vueltas = 0;
var a = "";
while(vueltas < 10){
  a += "<tr>"
  + "<td>" + monto + "</td>"
  + "<td>" + pesos + "</td>"
  + "</tr>";
        
        
  vueltas ++;
  monto ++;
  dolar = vueltas;
  pesos = monto * precioDolar;
}
      
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = a;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Dolar</th>
          <th>Peso</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="resultado">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No había visto tu respuesta, justo había considerado los puntos que indicas.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios errores encontrados en tu código.

- `17,10`: declaración errónea de un decimales, *considera al punto (`.`) como separador de decimales*
- `dolar +;`: mal uso del incrementador, deberías considerar `i++;`

---

Para resolver tu problema sería construir el cuerpo de tu tabla para luego asignarlo al elemento `tbody`, para lo cual le puse el id `contenedor` y a través del método `documento.getElementById()` busco al contenedor y le asigno a su propiedad `innerHTML` el cuerpo de tu tabla.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TablaDolar</title>
</head>
<body>

<table width="200" border="1">
    <tbody id="contenedor">
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>

var monto = 0;
var dolar = 17.10; // Decimales
var a = "";
var vueltas = 0;

a += "<tr><td>Dolares</td><td>Monto</td></tr>"; // Cabecera

while(vueltas < 10){
    a += "<tr><td>" + dolar + "</td><td>" + monto + "</td></tr>";

    vueltas++;
    dolar++; // Incrementador
    monto++;
}

document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = a;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**Referencias:**

- [Método getElementById()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)
- [Propiedad innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma es:

```js
const resultados = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0], dollar = 17.10; // Obtenemos el <tbody></tbody> y declaramos como constante el dólar.
var i = 1; //i de iteración 
var contenidos = [];// Creamos un array que contendrá todos los <tr> <td>iteración</td> <td>iteración * dollar</td> </tr>

while (i < 11)  //Si sólo es una instrucción en el ciclo podemos omitir los { }
    contenidos.push("<tr><td>"+i+"</td><td>"+i++*dollar+"</td></tr>"); // el i++ * dollar se incrementa la variable y a la vez se multiplica, esto permite tenerlo en una sola línea.

resultados.innerHTML = contenidos.join(""); // añadir al <tbody></tbody> los contenidos, pero como es un array está de la forma ["<tr>...</tr>", "<tr>...</tr>"] por lo que hay que unir todo en uno sólo, de ahí el join.
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Dólares</th>
            <th>Monto</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

A veces el `+=` puede afectar al rendimiento pues por ejemplo, en la décima iteración sería algo así:

```
<tr>......</tr>*9 = <tr>......</tr>*9 + <tr>......</tr>
```

Es decir las nueve filas son igual a las 9 filas más otra, que en realidad, gracias a *JS* no es tanto problema, pero no es así cuando son muchas iteraciones.

Por otro lado al usar `push()` no tienes que trabajar con todos los elementos anteriores, sólo con el último.

Pero en realidad para tu ejemplo puedes usar el que más te acomodes pues en realidad no hay mucho problema con esto del rendimiento.

Answer (score -2):

El encabezado de la tabla debería estar por fuera del while asi :

```
<table width="200" border="1">
 <tbody>
   <tr id="result"></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    while(vueltas < 10){
       a = "<td>" + dolar + "</td>"
       + "<td>" + monto + "</td>";
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = a;
       vueltas ++;
       dolar +;
       monto ++;
     }
</script>
```

Comment: El código tal cual expones tiene errores al momento de ejecutarlo.

Comment: claro tienes que declar las variables primero

Comment: En `dolar +;` a ver dime, ¿Que tipo de incrementador es?. Puedes revisar [Ejemplos JavaScript operadores incremento y decremento](http://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=796:ejemplos-javascript-operadores-incremento-y-decremento-asignacion-y-asignacion-compuesta-cu01118e&catid=78&Itemid=206).

Comment: bueno lo escribí de una, pero la idea de lo que debería hacer esta allí.

Comment: Te comprendo, pero con la **idea** que indicas puedes ampliar los problemas que tenga el OP y al final no llegaría a solucionar su problema inicial.

Comment: bueno señor....